# Automatically adapt listbox column width

Tags: vba, excel

I programmatically add elements from a database to a multicolumn listbox using this code :

```
Do While (Not rs.EOF) 

        ExistingSheetsListBox.AddItem
        ExistingSheetsListBox.List(i, 0) = rs.Fields(0)
        ExistingSheetsListBox.List(i, 1) = rs.Fields(1)
        ExistingSheetsListBox.List(i, 2) = rs.Fields(2)
        ExistingSheetsListBox.List(i, 3) = rs.Fields(3)
        ExistingSheetsListBox.List(i, 4) = rs.Fields(4)

        i = i + 1

        rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

The insertion in the listbox works fine, but the column width is not always adapted to the length of the elements inserted in it, I would like to know how I can do so that the column width of each column is adapted to the text inserted into it.

**EDIT** : I used the solution proposed by @Excel Developers with the piece of code given by @HarveyFrench.

Comment: You can do that in .Net, but I don't think you can in VBA. You will have to work out the width required by the longest entry and then set it to that value during runtime.

Comment: There is a fairly involved workaround [here](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/AutoSizeListBox01.asp) which involves using a hidden label that gets set to the longest item in each column and then the width property is read from that label and used to determine listbox column size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ColumnWidths property to set the size of the columns.

eg `ExistingSheetsListBox.ColumnWidths = "60;60;160;160;60"

For more info see [here](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/populate_userform_listbox_or_combobox.html)

I have not found anyway to automatically set the widths depending ont he data in each column, and I am pretty sure such a method does not exist.

Comment: If you set it to a font such as Courier New, that has the same width for each character, then you can count the number of characters and set the width of the listbox according to that. Just need to figure out how big is 1 charater in term of pixels (pretty sure it's been done already).

Answer (score 5):

There is no autosize option, following sample code shows 2 ways to do this.

This does not take into account anything other than being a sample.

Class Module clsListCtrlWidths

```
'class option used so we can use Collection instead of an array.
Option Explicit
Public m_ColWidthMax As Long
```

Forms Module. Initialise somewhere

```
Dim l_ColumnWidths As Collection
Set l_ColumnWidths = New Collection
```

Forms Module functions

```
Private Function SetColWidth(stLen As String, ctCol1 As control, lPosCol As Long) As String
    Dim stWidthTemp As String

    If lPosCol > 0 Then
        stWidthTemp = stLen & ";"
    End If

    Dim lTmpWidth As Long
    Dim lColWidth As Long
    lTmpWidth = ctCol1.Width
    ctCol1.AutoSize = True
    lColWidth = ctCol1.Width
    ctCol1.AutoSize = False
    ctCol1.Width = lTmpWidth

    If l_ColumnWidths.Count > lPosCol Then
        If l_ColumnWidths.Item(lPosCol + 1).m_ColWidthMax < lColWidth Then
            l_ColumnWidths.Item(lPosCol + 1).m_ColWidthMax = lColWidth
        Else
            lColWidth = l_ColumnWidths.Item(lPosCol + 1).m_ColWidthMax
        End If
    Else
        Dim clsColWidth As clsListCtrlWidths
        Set clsColWidth = New clsListCtrlWidths
        clsColWidth.m_ColWidthMax = lColWidth
        l_ColumnWidths.Add clsColWidth
    End If

    stWidthTemp = stWidthTemp & lColWidth
    SetColWidth = stWidthTemp
End Function
```

Following function takes listbox & calls on above function;

```
Private Function AutoSizeColsWidth(ByRef ctListCtrl As MSForms.ListBox)
    Dim txtBoxDummy As control
    Set txtBoxDummy = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txtBoxDummy", False)
    txtBoxDummy.AutoSize = True

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim strColWidth As String

    For lRow = 0 To ctListCtrl.ListCount - 1
        For lCol = 0 To ctListCtrl.ColumnCount - 1
            txtBoxDummy = ctListCtrl.List(lRow, lCol)
            strColWidth = SetColWidth(strColWidth, txtBoxDummy, lCol)
        Next lCol
    Next lRow

    ctListCtrl.ColumnWidths = strColWidth

End Function
```

1. Size Each time you add a single item

   ```
   'assumes rs.Fields is a control or converted to control
   Dim strColWidth As String
   strColWidth = SetColWidth(strColWidth, rs.Fields(0), 0)
   strColWidth = SetColWidth(strColWidth, rs.Fields(1), 1)
   strColWidth = SetColWidth(strColWidth, rs.Fields(2), 2)
   strColWidth = SetColWidth(strColWidth, rs.Fields(3), 3)
   'etc
   ctListCtrl.ColumnWidths = strColWidth
   ```
2. Or size once after adding lot of items

   ```
   Call AutoSizeColsWidth(myListBox) 'call after completely loading listbox
   ```

Added as I was looking for a way to do this & OP is Google's top answer.

Answer (score 0):

Read the width of the existing column and assign it to a variable and use that in the listbox column property.

For Example You have six columns A to F and You need to auto fit the column F

```
 FWidth = Columns("F").ColumnWidth * 7.6
   
 ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "120,120,120,120,120," & FWidth & ""
```

The Multiply of 7.6 will converts the value to Points.
In Similar Way You can do it for all of Your columns.

Answer (score 0):

Autosize Listbox and Combobox Columns with this function and Optionaly Resize Listbox/Combobox controls themselves.

```vb
Function ControlsResizeColumns(LBox As MSForms.Control, Optional ResizeListbox As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If sheetExists("ListboxColumnWidth", ThisWorkbook) = False Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ws.Name = "ListboxColumnwidth"
    Else
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ListboxColumnwidth")
        ws.Cells.Clear
    End If

    '---Listbox/Combobox to range-----
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ListboxColumnwidth").Range("A1")
    Set rng = rng.Resize(UBound(LBox.List) + 1, LBox.ColumnCount)
    rng = LBox.List
    rng.Characters.Font.Name = UserForm1.ListBox1.Font.Name
    rng.Characters.Font.Size = UserForm1.ListBox1.Font.Size
    rng.Columns.AutoFit
    
    '---Get ColumnWidths------
    rng.Columns.AutoFit
    Dim sWidth As String
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng.Resize(1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = cell.EntireColumn.Width + 10 'if not some extra space it cuts a bit off the tail
    Next cell

    sWidth = Join(vR, ";")
    Debug.Print sWidth

    '---assign ColumnWidths----
    With LBox
        .ColumnWidths = sWidth
        '.RowSource = "A1:A3"
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    End With

    '----Optionaly Resize Listbox/Combobox--------
    If ResizeListbox = True Then
        Dim w As Long

        For i = LBound(vR) To UBound(vR)
            w = w + vR(i)
        Next

        DoEvents
        LBox.Width = w + 10
    End If
        
    'remove worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function

Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String, Optional InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    If InWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set InWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    sheetExists = Not InWorkbook.Sheets(sheetToFind) Is Nothing
End Function
```